# How to get water from Storage Tank to Pressure Tank set at 75psi cutoff?

Tags: well-pump

I am planning to use water storage tanks for rainwater collection and distribute the water from a nearby pressure tank with a switch set at 55 psi to 75 psi to meet my needs. How many psi should the pump be rated for in order to fill the pressure tank?

For further clarification: The water storage tank(s) will hold about 3000 gallons of non-pressurized water. I am looking for a pump to take water from those tanks and put it into a pressure tank. The water will be distributed from the pressure tank to various usage points. I want the pressure tank's pressure switch to be set to turn the pump on at 55 psi and to turn it off at 75 psi. Many of the residential shallow well pumps are only rated to deliver up to about 60 psi, but I have found a few that deliver 80-87 psi max. I was wondering how much psi you would recommend for whatever pump I choose to fill my pressure tank? Are there other options?

Comment: This is not terribly clear - does the tank have another pump attached to it already, or it's dedicated to this use? Usually the pump will be rated in feet (or meters) of head, and you'll need one that supplies the flow you want (or more) at 173 Feet of Head + or - the difference in elevation of the pressure tank relative to the storage tanks.

Comment: The water storage tank is non-pressurized 3000 gallon tank. I need a way to get the water from that tank into a pressure tank. So I need a pump to move the water from the non-pressurized tank to a pressure tank. How strong does the pump have to be? If I use a shallow well pump, most are rated for no more than 60 psi. A few are rated for 80 psi. So can a shallow well pump rated for 80 psi fill a pressure tank with cutoff set at 75 psi, or does it need to be stronger? I left it vague because maybe there is a pump type that I do not know about and you could inform me about. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your comment would be much more visible to everyone if you were to [edit] your post and put that info directly into the question. With your 100 point bonus, you've been around SE long enough to know that comment can and do disappear...

Comment: You can drop a submersible pump into the tank, usually with a "sleeve" to ensure that water flows around the motor properly for cooling. But in that case you have to make sure the pump sees enough resistance that it does not overload (you might need a flow limiter inline with it, for instance.) For most purposes, you could also change the pressure switch settings to a lower value (*e.g.* 30-50 PSI) - do you have a specific need for 55-75, or it's just what your switch is currently set at?

Comment: @FreeMan How is that? I am only checking back on this occasionally through the day. Sorry that I cannot be quicker.

Answer (score 2):

The pump has to be capable of producing pressure that is greater than that in the tank.  So it should have a minimum output pressure of more than 75 psi.

You will use a pressure switch to turn it off when the target pressure is reached.

Comment: Thank you jwh20. Do you have any recommendation for how much more than 75 psi?

Comment: I'd be looking for anything with a rating of about 80 psi to 100 psi or so.